# Query regarding conversion of data from string to float in C++

Tags: c++

I have data of the following form:

```
7630000.0
2150000.0
5.85E7
4810000.0
1.863E8
2023428.2112
3.365126E9
```

I read this data line by line and convert the string's into floating point numbers using C++ function atof(). However, I find that certain data items like 3.365126E9 are wrongly getting converted by atof() into 18446744071562067968. Can someone suggest as to how should I do the appropriate conversion?

I am using C++ with GCC and G++ on ubuntu 12.04

Comment: There's an example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/78529/

Comment: Not sure why you're using `atof` since you tagged this C++.  You could read directly into a float or use a stringstream to convert.  http://ideone.com/4hhGku

Answer (score 1):

With C++11 there is stod, which is string to double.

Here is a quick example using sstream:

```
#include <iostream>   // std::cout
#include <string>     // std::string, std::stod
#include <sstream>   //std::istring

int main ()
{
    std::string example = "5.85E7";
    std::istringstream   os;
    os.str(example);
    double output;
    os >> output;
    std::cout << output << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

A more sophisticated method would be:

```
#include <iostream>   // std::cout
#include <string>     // std::string, std::stod
#include <sstream>   //std::istring

double StringToDouble(const std::string & text){
    std::istringstream   os;
    double output;
    os.str(text);
    os >> output;
    return output;
}    

int main ()
{
    std::string example = "5.85E7";
    std::cout << StringToDouble(example) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

More detailed explanation can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/D9j2Nwbp/)